How to Disable HTTP Access Logs in WSO2 Micro Integrator
I am currently using WSO2 Micro Integrator and I'm looking to completely disable HTTP access logs to optimize performance and reduce unnecessary I/O operations.
I have tried several configurations but have not yet succeeded in completely disabling the access logs.
I would greatly appreciate any advice or additional steps that could help me completely disable the HTTP access logs in WSO2 Micro Integrator.

You can disable it by removing the passthrough logger from loggers in MI_HOME/conf/log4j2.properties.
Open log4j.properties file and search for
loggers = PassThroughAccess, AUDIT_LOG, SERVICE_LOGGER, trace-messages,..... section and remove PassThroughAccess from the list.
Restart the server and verify.
